# Interactive debug console for scala in Intellij?

Tags: scala, debugging, intellij-idea

I am learning scala in my free time. When I was programming in python with Pycharm, Pycharm provides a very handy tool called `debug console` which, if I set a breakpoint at line L, would store the value of the variables by the time of L, and I can freely explore some operations on those variables.

I know scala has a REPL tool and I am wondering if scala in Intellij IDEA has the similar `debug console`. I know I can use `evaluate expression` tool but it is a little difficult to use because

1. I can't see the previous calculated expression values and I have to retype every time to see the values.
2. I can't store the result of the expression on one variable and continue using that variable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a breakpoint on a line (click in left margin to get a red dot) and then Debug rather than Run (bug icon rather than play icon) then IntelliJ will stop at the first breakpoint and show a very comprehensive debugging window. You can evaluate an expression (calculator icon) and create a watch expression which is evaluated each time a breakpoint is hit (watch panel on the right).